# PlaySound plays beep sound instead of my .wav file

Tags: c++, winapi, winmm

I'm making a simple console game and I'm using **PlaySound()** to implement a media player to play sfx of the game. However, all I can listen to is the Windows beep sound, not my intended sound. I've tried everything from putting the files into the current directory, using full path but nothing works.

```
PlaySound(TEXT("E:\\losing.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

Comment: Show the code, please

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Added now

Comment: Add the SND_NODEFAULT flag.  And don't ignore the return value while debugging.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)): "*If the file cannot be found, the function plays the default sound unless the SND_NODEFAULT flag is set.*"

Comment: Make sure the file actually is a valid .wav file.

Comment: @IInspectable I've tried playing it and yeah, it plays

Comment: @Tùng, the file you're trying to play, was it in a different format? Like, did you convert the file from another format to .wav format by simply changing .mp3 to .wav? Try with one of the files from https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/

Comment: There are countless audio file formats. The fact that some audio player can play it isn't sufficient. `PlaySound` requires a particular audio format, [WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV).